# Could not connect to Endpoint for second peer on Hyperledger using Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, docker-swarm

I have followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f) using VirtualBox and everything worked well. Now I'm following it again using real servers.
And when I am trying to set up the second peer, I get this message:

> 2020-06-14 02:33:25.258 UTC [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 02f Could
>   not connect to Endpoint: peer0.org1.example.com:7051,
>   InternalEndpoint: peer0.org1.example.com:7051, PKI-ID: ,
>   Metadata:  : context deadline exceeded

I have done everything exactly the same but it does not work. Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Have you set up the following environment variable: `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP` for both of your peers?

Comment: @user204415 please shre your config files and logs.